# Which one is a better scheduler in AWS Data Pipeline and AWS SWF

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-swf, amazon-data-pipeline

I have a situation where I have to trigger my workflow based on this condition `"It has to process all files in s3 and then start again when there are files in s3"`. However, I found that Data Pipeline starts every scheduled duration while SWF starts and ends the job which also shut downs my EMR Cluster. Both of them are not suitable in this case. So, for a process which has to start or trigger based on a condition neither is suitable is what I found. Is there any alternative? Or is one of SWF and Data Pipeline could perform my task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more like @Chris's answer's corollary. You still make use of Lambda - listen to S3 - Put Event trigger - so every time when there is a new object being create - the lamdba function would be called.

The Lambda Function can pick up the S3 object's key and put it in SQS; you can run a separate Worker Process which can pick items from the Queue.

To reiterate your statement,

1. It has to process all files in s3 **[ Can be Done by Lambda ]**
2. and then start again when there are files in s3 **[Can be Done by SQS & EC2 ]**

Comment: This is actually an excellent way to avoid having to poll S3.

Comment: The another good thing about this method is to the ability to spot instance. You can make the queue to hold the items for 14 days; can do a cron / process on every day or weekly to process the queue. It is all decoupled

Comment: Have a look at [Configuring Amazon S3 Event Notifications](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html) - S3 can trigger SQS, SNS and Lambda automatically, so unless I'm missing something, it doesn't really make sense to use Lambda and push to SQS.

Comment: Completely agree with your point; also - the idea is to do little bit of pre-processing [ in the lamdba / using the lambda ] - rather than having - 2 queues [ Well actually trying to defend my answer :P :) ]

Comment: @Naveen: Lambda seems to be adding functionality rather quickly, so things that were not available in Feb. 2015 may be there by the time someone finds this question again.

Answer (score 2):

Look at Lambda.  You can set up a trigger so that your code is invoked each time a new object is uploaded to S3.

Comment: What if I have 1000 files coming up at the same time, would it process all of them at the same time and still continue for every file coming.

Comment: That is the claim: http://aws.amazon.com/lambda/details/ - "There is no limit to the number of requests your code can handle"

Comment: It helps. Are there any samples.

Comment: I did not find a way where my java jar file which performs some computations can run on Lambda.

Comment: Lambda currently only support node.js code, although given Amazon's history I suspect at some point in the future java will be an option.

Comment: Java is now available in Lambda (this comment is coming from summer 2015)

Comment: Python is now available in Lambda (re:invent 2015)

Answer (score 2):

Data Pipeline supports the concept of [Preconconditions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-S3KeyExists.html) which can trigger your execution based on conditions. The `S3KeyExists` preconditions seems like what you're looking for. This will begin the execution of your activity when a particular S3 key exists.

Data Pipeline will also manage the creation and termination of your resource (EC2 or EMR) based on the activity's execution. If you wish to use your own EC2 instance or EMR cluster you can look into worker groups. Worker group resources are managed by you and will not be terminated by the service.

Comment: Could you suggest any java samples for this.